Obtener el último registro de una tabla en postgresql
Tengo este código para buscar el último registro, pero no lo trae:
$stmt = pg_prepare($connect, "MaxNroHistoria", "SELECT max(nrohistoria) as MaxNroHistoria FROM pacientes");

    // Ejecutar la consulta
    $result = pg_execute($connect, "MaxNroHistoria", array());
    
    if ($result) {
        $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($row) { // Verificar si $row no es null
            $maxNroHistoria = $row['MaxNroHistoria'];
            echo "<table align='center'><tr><td class='sr'>Ultimo Nro de Historia:<input type='text' readonly='f' value='$maxNroHistoria' name='nrohistoria' size='10' maxlength='10' align='right' class='color1'/></td></tr></table>";
        } else {
            echo "No se encontraron registros.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta: " . pg_last_error($connect);
    }


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No se entiende tu problema. porque no describis ningun problema....

¿Estás manejando los errores de tu aplicación correctamente?

¿Si ejecutas directamente SELECT max(nrohistoria) as MaxNroHistoria FROM pacientes; en la base de datos arroja algo? ¿Cuál es tu versión de PostgreSQL?

la version que tengo es esta: PostgreSQL 17.0 on x86_64-windows, compiled by msvc-19.41.34120, 64-bit  y he corrido la consulta que me has indicado y arroja este resultado: maxnrohistoria
22 pero aparece tambien un candado en esa consulta, será ese el problema? y quisiera saber que funciones debo activar en el php.ini. Te agradezo l ayuda amigo Cedano

he instalado XAMPP Version: 8.2.12 y no aparece esta linea extension=php_pgsql.dll, la verdad no se cual es el conflicto.

tambien te comento que yo migré de windows 7 al windows 10.

ahora el resultado me arroja que es NULL. Pero la tabla tiene registros

Desde tu herramienta de administración de base de datos (PHPMyAdmin, pgAdmin, DBeaver, o lo que tengas), si ejecutás la misma consulta, ¿qué resultado devuelve?
